# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, update, st-geometry

I was trying to update one table based on the spatial join table.  When I try to run following code:

```
UPDATE p
SET 
    p.mileage = ip.length_unusually
FROM 
    PIPELINE p
JOIN 
    intersected_pipeline ip
ON 
    sde.st_intersects(p.SHAPE, ip.SHAPE)=1;
```

I get following error

Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:

I am not sure about the cause

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the client you are using to submbt the SQL to Oracle (hint: The semicolon is *not* part of the SQL statement).

Comment: Also you flagged this as related to Oracle Spatial: it is not. You are using ESRI’s spatial operators.

Comment: Finally you write UPDATE P, i.e. the alias of the table you mention in your query. That should be UPDATE PIPELINE